# Using Multiple Where-And in Fetching From Database - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How can I do this in Laravel 5.1?

> Select * from articles where 'completed' '==' '0' and 'created_by_id' == 'current user id'

I tried something like this but unfortunately didn't work:

```
 $projects = Project::latest('created_at')->where('created_by_id', '==', Auth::id())
                    ->where('completed', '==', "0")->get();
```

This works:

```
 $projects = Project::latest('created_at')->where('completed', '==', "0")->get();
```

But this doesn't:

```
 $projects = Project::latest('created_at')->where('created_by_id', '==', Auth::id())-get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a little fix:

```
$project = Project::where('created_by_id','=',Auth::user()->id)->where('completed','=',0)->latest()->get()
```

latest has "created_at" as default argument.

MySQL uses =, not == for comparison.

You must first call the user() method on Auth, and then the id property.